# Unable to reference class variable require 'self' keyword

Tags: ios, swift

How to get holidays to be updated when using the self keyword? When access outside the particular function the variable is still empty. The below code is inside a view controller class

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import UIKit    


var holidays = [Holiday]()   

        func loadSampleHoliday(){

                    var holidayObject = Holiday(holidayName: "", holidayDate: "")

                    request(.GET,"URL").responseJSON{
                        response in
                        switch response.result{
                        case .Success(let data):
                            let json = JSON(data)
                            let numberOfHoliday = data.count
                            //var holidayObject : Holiday
                            for (var index = 0; index < numberOfHoliday; ++index){
                                let phDate = json[index]["eventDate"].stringValue
                                let phName = json[index]["eventName"].stringValue
                                holidayObject = Holiday(holidayName: "\(phName)", holidayDate: "\(phDate)")
                                //holidays variable only updated locally
                                // how make the variable updated globally?
                                self.holidays += [holidayObject];

                            }
                            break;
                        case .Failure(let error):
                            print("Request failed");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You need to make sure you are accessing `self.holidays` *after* the asynchronous network operation has been completed.

Comment: @Paulw11, thank you for your answer, but tried to using `self.holidays` after the asyn network operation but returned value is 0 if accessed within the function it will returned value of 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `loadSampleHoliday()` shouldn't modify `holidays` directly. Because it's an async operation, you should add a closure as parameter of this function to be able to execute code **after** the async operation is done.

So you could do something like that :

```
func loadSampleHoliday(completion:([Holiday]) -> ()) {

    request(.GET,"URL").responseJSON {
        response in
        //Create a local array
        var holidays = [Holiday]()

        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let data):
            let json = JSON(data)
            let numberOfHoliday = data.count                
            var holidayObject : Holiday
            for (var index = 0; index < numberOfHoliday; ++index){
                let phDate = json[index]["eventDate"].stringValue
                let phName = json[index]["eventName"].stringValue
                holidayObject = Holiday(holidayName: "\(phName)", holidayDate: "\(phDate)")
                holidays.append(holidayObject)   
            }
            break;
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed");
            break;
        }
        completion(holidays)
    }
}
```

and then call it that way :

```
loadSampleHoliday { sampleHolidays in
    self.holidays = sampleHolidays
    //Do what you want next
}
```

Now `loadSampleHoliday` has only the responsability to fetch the sample holidays, you can do what you want with the result. It's more reusable, it's more readable and you are sure that the async operation is done when the code within the closure is executed.